# Multithreading in javascript through setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, events

My idea is to build a list of threads into a global object threads and then call a function threadmanager:

```
function threadmanager()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++)
    {
        if (threads[i]) 
        {
            threads[i].run();
            if (threads[i].done) threads[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    setTimeout(threadmanager, 100);
}
```

Is this a workable implementation of multithreading in javascript or am I missing something? Has somebody done something along these lines?

Comment: You're missing that js is singlethreaded.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can control threading through setTimeout, because I'm pretty sure the browser does that, so it all depends on the browser. Also, it's a good idea to make a loop with `setInterval` instead of using recurision in some cases

Comment: If your interested in Threading with Javascript, you might want to look into WebWorkers.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze The code above seems quite multithreaded to me :)

Comment: @zevee I haven't used recursion.

Comment: @Keith I have already looked into the Worker thing. It seems rather inflexible because you must have a separate js file for each thread/worker right? And you must communicate by sending messages and the worker responding through av event handler...

Comment: As implied by above comments, the best you would achieve with a standard JS engine is managing processing chunks on a **single** computing unit, because that is all that is available to the engine. Workers are indeed the main solution for actually processing _simultaneously_, i.e. taking advantage of multiple computing units (in case there are multiple CPU's / cores available).

Comment: @Henrik3 a function calling itself? Sounds like recrusion to me

Comment: @ghybs Ah but now you mean physical concurrency. That has nothing to do with multithreading which is a logical virtual thing.

Comment: What your trying to do with setTimeout has nothing to do with multithreading.  The word multi(thread)ing, is the clue.

Comment: @Henrik3 ok so you know the difference! Then you should make it much clearer in your question, because you are confusing all above commenters (and very probably even more people). Note that _multithreading_ means different things in different environments. In JavaScript, it refers to trying to take advantage of multiple physical CPU's / cores (example: https://keithwhor.github.io/multithread.js/).

Comment: @zevee The function isn't calling itself. setTimeout doesn't call the function, it schedules it for running. Later the SYSTEM will call the function.

Comment: @Henrik3  A better wording for what your doing might be  `Asynchronous Manager`

Comment: @Henrik3 It is still a function indirectly calling itself, setting itself up to be run again. Using `setInterval` can be better because you can use `var something = setInterval(somethingsomething, 100);` and then if you need to stop the process you can type `clearInterval(something)`

Comment: @Keith I mean multithreading in the standard sense. Compare with C++ and Java if you wish.

Comment: @zevee No. Learn about recursion. I cannot use, nor do I need setInterval.

Comment: @Henrik3  A thread is a thread, doesn't matter if it's in C++,C#,Javascript or Java etc..  setTimeout doesn't create a new thread, please stop using the term when it's not relevant, if you want threads that's the WebWorker.

Comment: @Keith As I said, threads are a logical thing. It doesn't matter how you implement them, they will still be threads. I'm not saying setTimeout creates a new thread, I'm suggesting that the function above implements multithreading. What functionality are you missing?

Comment: `threads are a logical thing.`, no there a physical thing. What makes you think there logical?. Are you getting mixed up with `multitasking`?  With threads you can do 2 things at exactly the same time, that's why in C++ and other languages that have them, there is something called thread safety, here even to increment a number can be tricky.  Using setTimeout, you will not be executing 2 things at exactly the same time, because it's a single thread.

Comment: "The code above seems quite multithreaded to me :)" I don't think so ..

Comment: @Keith OK, so you just don't know anything about multithreading. Study then!  Multitasking isn't physical concurrency either. It COULD be implemented as such, but it doesn't matter to the concept. C++ has physical concurrency? C++ is just a spec and it doesn't say anything about that. You may know that you can compile and run C++ programs on computers which are strictly sequential.

Comment: @Henrik3  Your making a silly mistake assuming I'm just a Javascript programmer,.  I learnt from the days of C, C++, Delphi etc, I certainly know what a Thread is, I've no need or desire to go and study any more.  But if you want to pretend your making a Multi Threaded manager using setTimeout, then go ahead nobody is stopping you.  And I've never said anything about C++ was just about multi-threading, indeed I was using C++ on .8086, and 16bit Windows 3.11.  I await your next pointless ramble with baited breath..